# On the evaluation of $\sum\limits_3^\infty \frac1{\ln\Gamma(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics, gamma-function, constants

**Motivation:**

This question will be inspired from:

> [Evaluation of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{\text G(n)}≈ 3+\frac{\,_0\rm F_2(2,3;1)}2 $ with the Barnes G function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297098/evaluation-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1-text-gn%e2%89%88-3-frac-0-rm-f-2) and [Evaluating $\sum\limits_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{!x}$ in exact form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218525/evaluating-sum-limits-x-2-infty-frac1x-in-exact-form)

with references from:

> [Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^t}\,dt$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673109/evaluate-int-0-infty-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1nnt-dt/2673141)

**The Puzzle:**

we will make heavy use of the [Logarithm of the Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogGamma/) which is technically its own function:

$$\text{ln}\Gamma(x)=\text{log}\Gamma(x)=\ln(\Gamma(x)$$

Here is the goal sum with $n\ge3$ or else the sum would diverge:

$$\sum_3^\infty \frac1{\text{ln}\Gamma(n)}$$

According to the reference question:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\log\Gamma(n+1)}= \sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\log\Gamma(n)}= \int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^t}\,dt \implies -\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n!)^t}dt\mathop = ^?\sum_3^\infty \frac1{\text{ln}\Gamma(n)} $$

Using this logic, let’s use the [Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/) which may require $t\in\Bbb N$, but is still interesting:

$$-\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n!)^t}dt=-\int_0^\infty\,_0\text F_{t-1}(1,…,1)dt$$

The first question is if the sum converges and the sum converges slowly. Maybe we can use a comparison test with a [Stirling’s Approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) would work, but even it’s convergence is hard to use. Here are the partial sums:

[image]

Does our goal sum converge and if so, then what is an alternate form of it? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe

$$ \begin{array}{lcl} 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln n!} & > &
\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln n^n} \\[5pt]
& = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln n} \\[5pt]
& > & \displaystyle \int_2^{N+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\ln x} \\[5pt]
& = & \displaystyle \ln\ln N+\mathcal{O}(1)
\end{array} $$